# How to make sure django migration for deleting columns is done before data migration from those columns into another table

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models

I have 2 apps in Dajngo, A and B, which each have their own models.

I'm in charge of a task that moving some fields/columns from A's model to B's

Before:

```
class Amodel:
    fieldA = models.BooleanField(....
    fieldB = models.....
    fieldC = ........

class Bmodel:
    fieldD = models......
```

After:

```
class Amodel:
    fieldC = ........

class Bmodel:
    fieldA = models.BooleanField(....
    fieldB = models.....
    fieldD = models......
```

This is a bit confusing how I structure this example, but Amodel and Bmodel are in DIFFERENT apps

I set up 2 migration files, one in B to add new columns in table and migrate the data from A, another in A to remove these fields

When I run tests, A's deletion is triggered before B's data migration. How do I deal with this?

For some info that might be related:

```
Django: 1.11
Postgres: 9.5
```

Comment: You can make 3 migrations. The first one will add new fields to the Bmodel, the second one will transfer the data and the third will remove the fields from the Amodel.

Comment: @Johan why would this prevent Amodel's migration file being executed first before Bmodel's? I'm sorry I don't quite understand migrations orders

Comment: Because migrations are executed in the order they are created. For every `makemigration` command you execute a migration file with an ordered number is created.

Comment: @Johan I think @Alex's answer is the correct one. I have two apps here. `makemigrations` only create dependencies on the same app. App A and app B don't talk to each other this way unless I manually set it

Comment: You're correct, I didn't think of the criteria and limitations of having 2 separate apps making relations two each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see the entire process:

- You add new fields on `Bmodel` and generate the migration for that (`app_b/migrations/0001_new_fields.py`)
- Now, you want to make a data migration to move data from Amodel to Bmodel (`app_a/migrations/0001_fancy_data_migration.py`).

  For this one we'll set the following dependecy:

  ```py
  dependencies = [
      ('app_b', '0001_new_fields'),
  ]
  ```

  making sure it will run only after we added the new fields.
- Since we migrated all the important data, we're ready to drop fields from `Amodel`. We'll be removing them and generate the corresponding migration (`app_a/migrations/0002_drop_fields.py`).

  This time, the dependencies for this migration will look something like this:

  ```py
   dependencies = [
       ('app_a', '0001_fancy_data_migraiton'),
   ]
  ```

Comment: ah.... I see. So we are allowed to set dependency on other apps. I can also set multiple dependencies, this way, namely `[('app_b', '0001_new_fields'), ('app_a', '000x_some_old_migrations_I_want_to_keep_on_track')]`, correct?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to do so.